# Assigning objects to variables in java

Tags: java, object, breakout

hi im making a game of breakout and im having a problem with getting the ball to bounce off the paddle or the bricks.

Heres my code for to make the ball bounce off the bricks and paddle.

```
private void checkForHit(){
    GObject collider = getElementAt( ballX, ballspeed);

    if(collider == paddle){
        ballspeed = -ballspeed;
    }
}
```

I don't know why its not working, its probably something small.

UPDATE

when i put set if(collider.equals(paddle))

i get an java.lang.NullPointerException error when i run the game.

Comment: Whats `paddle`? also a `GObject?`

Comment: Well, that makes two of us. I don't know why it's not working either. An error message or a more thorough description may help us identify your problem better. Does the ball go through? Maybe 'getElementAt' doesn't recognize the collider? Also, where's your 'Y' in this equation?

Comment: Be careful with the '==' comparison.  In Java, that does a comparison to see if the references both point to the same memory space.  If you want to check equality, then we usually do a .equals(), passing in the object.  By default, all Objects have a .equals(), but you can overwrite it to provide a custom implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your trying to use == signs on objects. The normal syntax when comparing objects is like CodeChimp explained:

```
<objectname>.equals( <otherobject> )
```

You have to make sure that the objects you are using (if you made them yourself) has an equal method to use and compares the correct fields values etc. with the other objects. It's a very important part of OOP to learn how to get objects to work together.

You might wanna take a look at the keyword:
    instanceof
while your at it.

Also if your just looking to compare two different field values, which is both fx integer values in each of the two classes you have. You could make a getter method for those field values and simple compare those specific values.

```
if ( collider.getSpecificValue() == paddle.getSpecificValue() ) { }
```